# How can I iterate over this php array

Tags: php, arrays, iteration, slim

I have this variable that `INSERTs` to a db the attached filename from a html form input.

```
$insertAttachments->execute( array(':attachment2' => $attachment2) );
```

Now the problem is it `INSERTs` only one filename although the input is set to allow multiple. So I tried to do this:

```
$uploads = count($attachment2);  //counts the number of attachments
for($i=0; $i<$uploads; $i++){
    $insertAttachments->execute( array(':attachment2' => $attachment2) );
}
```

which left me wondering where to place `[$i]` so that it iterates over `array(':attachment2' => $attachment2)`?

If I assign it a variable and have it like -

```
$alluploads = array(':attachment2' => $attachment2);
for($i=0; $i<$uploads; $i++){
    $insertAttachments->execute( $alluploads[$i] );
}
```

It runs into an error. Any ideas how I should pull this off? I'm extending a php 5.3 / slim framework application.

Comment: Use foreach instead

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood very basic PHP, array and loop functionality. I suggest reading some of the introduction tutorials on the topic.

Comment: are you aware that there is typo in the second example $alluploads!=$uploads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreach let's you iterate over an associative array.

```
$alluploads = array(':attachment2' => "attachment2");
foreach($alluploads as $key => $value){
    echo "key: " . $key . " Has value: ". $value ."\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/uPBug

---

Here is an example with a for loop using array_keys to get the associative array keys and using that in the loop.

```
$alluploads = array(':attachment2' => "attachment2");
$keys = array_keys($alluploads);
for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++){
    echo "key: " . $keys[$i] . " Has value: ". $alluploads[$keys[$i]] ."\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/45fnM

---

And as a third example you can use array_values to remove the associative keys.
This method should only be used if you know all the values in the arrays are uploads and should be treated the same.

```
$alluploads = array(':attachment2' => "attachment2");
$alluploads = array_values($alluploads);
for($i=0;$i<count($alluploads);$i++){
    echo "key: " . $i . " Has value: ". $alluploads[$i] ."\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/IrDrv

Comment: So by the third example, inside the `for` loop - will I be correct in saying `$insertAttachments->execute( array(':attachment2' => $alluploads[$i]) );` because `$alluploads[$i]` returns the value of attachment2?

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried both `execute( array(':attachment2' => $alluploads[$i]) )` and `execute( array($alluploads[$i]) )` and they both work. Thanks though.

Comment: @Clint_A The reason I placed them in that order is because foreach is the best answer, for with array_keys is an acceptable answer. And array_values works but should not really be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `foreach` loop, and that way you don't need the count, like this:

```
foreach ($attachment2 as $a){
    $insertAttachments->execute( array(':attachment2' => $a['some index with the file path']) );
}
```

Don't forget to change the index o the array